# Select foo with bar events only after a specific date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Consider two tables:

```
Foo:
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR

Bar:
  id INT,
  foo_id INT REFERENCES Foo(id),
  event SET('hit','miss'),
  ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Each Foo item can have multiple Bar events. **How to query for Foo items which *have* Bar events after a specific datetime, but which also *do not have* Bar events before that datetime?**

For instance, consider:

```
Foo id=1:
    hit 2014-01-21
    hit 2014-01-22
    hit 2014-01-23

Foo id=2:
    hit 2014-01-17
    hit 2014-01-19
    hit 2014-01-21

Foo id=3:
    hit 2014-01-14
    hit 2014-01-15
    hit 2014-01-18

Foo id=4:
    hit 2014-01-21
    hit 2014-01-22
    hit 2014-01-24
```

I would like to query only those Foo items with hits on or after `2014-01-20`, so that should return the ids `1` and `4`.

I have tried joining the `Bar` table to itself, using a few variations on the following:

```
SELECT
    b1.id
FROM
    Bar b1 JOIN Bar b2 using (foo_id)
WHERE
    b1.ts > '2014-01-20';
```

However, I don't see how to phrase the WHERE clause to exclude any combinations for which any date is before `2014-01-20`.

Comment: So the bar table is a bit like an events table?

Comment: @Strawberry: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   Foo.*
FROM     Foo JOIN Bar ON Bar.foo_id = Foo.id
GROUP BY Foo.id
HAVING   MIN(Bar.ts) >= '2014-01-20'
```

Or:

```
SELECT   Foo.*
FROM     Foo JOIN (
           SELECT   foo_id id, MIN(ts) min_ts
           FROM     Bar
           GROUP BY id
         ) t USING (id)
WHERE    t.min_ts >= '2014-01-20'
```

Or:

```
SELECT   Foo.*
FROM     Foo JOIN Bar ON Bar.foo_id = Foo.id
GROUP BY Foo.id
HAVING   SUM(Bar.ts >= '2014-01-20')
 AND NOT SUM(Bar.ts <  '2014-01-20')
```

Or:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     Foo
WHERE    EXISTS (
           SELECT *
           FROM   Bar
           WHERE  Bar.foo_id = Foo.id
              AND Bar.ts >= '2014-01-20'
         )
 AND NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT *
           FROM   Bar
           WHERE  Bar.foo_id = Foo.id
              AND Bar.ts <  '2014-01-20'
         )
```

Or:

```
SELECT   b1.foo_id
FROM     Bar b1 LEFT JOIN Bar b2
      ON b2.foo_id = b1.foo_id
     AND b2.ts <  '2014-01-20'
WHERE    b1.ts >= '2014-01-20'
     AND b2.foo_id IS NULL
GROUP BY b1.foo_id
```

Comment: Thank you, there are some terrific ideas here. +1, and I'll try them all before selecting an answer.

Comment: @dotancohen: To be honest, I'd go with the first solution - it's readable and performant.

Comment: I'm seeing that! However I need this to fit a variety of solutions on a heavily indexed table of almost 5,000,000 rows.